# Free monad - implicit Inject with nested Coproduct using cats

Tags: scala, scala-cats

Say I have three DSLs I want to use:

```
sealed trait Test1Op[A]
sealed trait Test2Op[A]
sealed trait Test3Op[A]

object Test1Op {
  case class Test1() extends Test1Op[String]
}

object Test2Op {
  case class Test2() extends Test2Op[String]
}

object Test3Op {
  case class Test3() extends Test3Op[String]
}
```

the final composition is:

```
type Api[A] = Coproduct[Test1Op, Coproduct[Test2Op, Test3Op, ?], A]
```

to make use of it I need appropriate `Inject` instances (which I believe I should be able to get implicitly as it is with just two DSLs and one coproduct):

```
  implicit val inj1: Inject[Test1Op, Api] = implicitly
  implicit val inj2: Inject[Test2Op, Api] = implicitly
  implicit val inj3: Inject[Test3Op, Api] = implicitly
```

this compiles fine. However at runtime they are all `null`.

// edit:

the problem above seems to be marking these vals as `implicit` (which causes recursive resolution). After removing `implicit` it seems to show the correct error, which is:

Error:(28, 36) ambiguous implicit values:
 both value StringCanBuildFrom in object Predef of type => scala.collection.generic.CanBuildFrom[String,Char,String]
 and method $conforms in object Predef of type [A]=> <:<[A,A]
 match expected type T
  def inj1: Inject[Test1Op, Api] = implicitly

and

Error:(28, 36) could not find implicit value for parameter e: T
  def inj1: Inject[Test1Op, Api] = implicitly

and

Error:(28, 36) type mismatch;
 found   : Unit
 required: cats.free.Inject[com.example.Test1Op,com.example.Hello.Api]
  def inj1: Inject[Test1Op, Api] = implicitly

Answer (score 1):

As usual, found solution just few minutes after asking a question:

1. Remove `implicit` (see question edit)
2. Spit `Api[A]` type:

   ```
   type PartialApi[A] = Coproduct[Test2Op, Test3Op, A]
   type Api[A] = Coproduct[Test1Op, PartialApi, A]
   ```
3. Profit from working implicit `Inject`!